# Can't select option in OSX Utilities

Tags: macos, mouse, utilities

I'm having a pretty bizarre problem in OSX Mavericks. I'm attempting to install a fresh version of the OS, so I boot to OSX Utilities (Cmd+R). The option that I'm looking for is listed (re-install operating system), but I can't select it or anything else from the list.

I can move the mouse around, but clicking does not work. I tried with both the trackpad as well as a USB mouse. I can navigate through the options with the arrow keys, but pressing enter has no effect.

How the heck am I supposed to do anything from the utilities?

Comment: Are you running the OS X Install application from your internal hard drive or from a separate volume (external hard disk, USB stick, etc.)? If the former, could it be that your Mac won't let you "write over" the existing installation?

Comment: I just had the same issue, I was able to get around the issue by turning on VoiceOver (Command-F5) then pressing CTRL + Option + Right arrow to navigate through the different elements on the page.  Once the Install button was highlighted, I was able to select it by pressing CTRL + Option + Space.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @BrianSalta nailed it. This experience has taught me the value of integrating accessibility controls.

Answer (score 7):

To get around this problem I went to the option I wanted with the **arrow keys** then got frustrated when I couldn`t click.

What I proceeded to do was start in the bottom right with the options key and push all the buttons across and up the next two rows skipping the Cap Locks. The continue button then illuminated. To then select it I pushed the **space bar**. Hope this works

Comment: Thank you Graham! This works for me.

Answer (score 4):

After you highlight the option you want with the arrow keys, press the "tab" button to highlight "continue" and then press spacebar to select.

Answer (score 0):

Click Harder!

Im not joking. Im experiencing the same issue, `tab` and `space` works good too. But I noticed that if I click the trackpad harder and for up to 5 seconds the click eventually registers.

Perhaps the trackpad needs some tuning that doesnt happen in recovery mode.

This is on a 2011 mac book pro with El Captian.

Answer (score -1):

As per the above - I had this issue, but I found that although I couldn't 'tap' on my trackpad, I could 'click' (press on bottom left of pad). Alternatively, the Tab key will move the cursor between sections of the window, arrow keys high-light an item within it, and the space bar selects it

Comment: OP states that he tried a USB mouse and that pressing enter does not work.